# bash for loop output on elements retrieved using yq is triplicated and not in expected sequence

Tags: bash, for-loop, yaml, yq

Here are the details of my issue:

`env-attributes.yml` contents:

```
environments:
- env_name: development
  account_id: "11111111111"
  account_name: myapp-dev
  user_id: svc-dev
- env_name: staging
  account_id: "22222222222"
  account_name: myapp-stg
  user_id: svc-stg
- env_name: production
  account_id: "33333333333"
  account_name: myapp-prod
  user_id: svc-prod
```

`parse-yml.sh` contents:

```
env_count=$(yq '.environments | length' env_attributes.yml)

for i in $(seq 1 $env_count)
do
  env_name=$(yq '.environments[$i].env_name' env_attributes.yml)
  account_id=$(yq '.environments[$i].account_id' env_attributes.yml)
  account_name=$(yq '.environments[$i].account_name' env_attributes.yml)
  user_id=$(yq '.environments[$i].user_id' env_attributes.yml)
  echo "${env_name}"
  echo "${account_id}"
  echo "${user_id}"
  echo " "
done
```

Running `parse-yml.sh`, I get the following output:

```
development
staging
production
11111111111
22222222222
33333333333
svc-dev
svc-stg
svc-prod
 
development
staging
production
11111111111
22222222222
33333333333
svc-dev
svc-stg
svc-prod
 
development
staging
production
11111111111
22222222222
33333333333
svc-dev
svc-stg
svc-prod
```

The expected output is:

```
development
11111111111
myapp-dev
svc-dev

staging
22222222222
myapp-stg
svc-stg

production
33333333333
myapp-prod
svc-prod
```

How can I get the expected output?